# Will setValidators work on TemplateDriven FormControl?

Tags: angular, forms

```
let filterInputControl: FormControl = this.addRequestFilterRef.gridFilterForm.form.get('filterName');

filterInputControl.setValidators([Validators.max(50)]);
```

I have a template driven form. From typescript i am fetching the FormControl and trying to update setValidators. But it is not working

Does setValidators work with templateDrivenFormControl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes  setValidators will work with templateDrivenFormControl